# Passing by reference - how does it work and why is it used?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pass-by-reference

Take the following code from CodeIgniter's `show_error` function:

`$_error =& load_class('Exceptions', 'core');`

The documentation for the `load_class` function says it acts as a singleton. The function basically takes the given parameters and searches for a class in the appropriate path.  It then includes the file if it exists. The function is declared as:

`function &load_class(...)`

Why does it have the & and what is its purpose? Is `$_error` declared as such as a result of defining the function like that?

Comment: So that you get a consistent CI object to work with. Things that modify properties, add overrides, etc, are done by reference so that you don't have individual CI objects that may not carry over to another object.

Comment: @Brendan: That doesn't make sense. The type of values returned by `load_class()` are object references (when you do `new Something` in PHP 5, that evaluates to an object reference). Copying or assigning object references by value do not create new objects; they create more object references that point to that object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The php [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php) seems to explain why you have to uses `=&` even though the function is marked to return a refrence `function &load_class`

> Returning References
>
> Returning by reference is useful when you want to use a function to
>   find to which variable a reference should be bound. Do not use
>   return-by-reference to increase performance. The engine will
>   automatically optimize this on its own. Only return references when
>   you have a valid technical reason to do so. To return references, use
>   this syntax:

```
 <?php class foo {
     public $value = 42;

     public function &getValue() {
         return $this->value;
     } 
  }



$obj = new foo; 
$myValue = &$obj->getValue(); // $myValue is a reference to $obj->value, which is 42.
$obj->value = 2; 
echo $myValue;
// prints the new value of $obj->value, i.e. 2. ?>
```

In this example,

> the property of the object returned by the getValue function would be
>   set, not the copy, as it would be without using reference syntax.
>   ***Note: Unlike parameter passing, here you have to use & in both places
>   - to indicate that you want to return by reference, not a copy, and to indicate that reference binding, rather than usual assignment, should
>   be done for $myValue.***

If you are asking what references in general are the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) explains.

Comment: But this doesn't make sense for the function in the question. The `load_class` function checks to see if there is a value in a dictionary for a certain key, if so returns it, if not creates an appropriate value, puts it into the dictionary, and returns it. Once the value for a key is put into that dictionary, it never sets another value for that key. So it is not like your example here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any point of declaring and using `load_class` like that. From the source code of `load_class()`, we can see that it caches loaded objects in an array with the class name as the key. If it is not in the cache, it loads an object given a name, and then stores that object reference into the array. In both cases, it returns the element of the array (by reference).

Returning by reference allows the caller to have a reference to the element of the array. The only things that this allows us to do are:

1. See later changes to that array element (i.e. the value associated with that key) from the outside reference we have. But this is not applicable, since the `load_class` function never changes the value associated with a key after it sets it.
2. Have external code be able to change the element in the array, without the `load_class` function knowing about it. But this would be a highly dubious practice, to mess with the cache from the outside, and I highly doubt this is something the authors wanted.

So there is no legitimate reason to return by reference. My guess is that it is a leftover from PHP 4, when objects were values, and so assigning or returning an "object value" would copy it. In PHP 5, objects are not values; you can only manipulate them through object references, and assigning or returning an object reference by value never copies the object it points to.